# Rails where with custom model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, notifications, rails-activerecord, where-clause

I'm using Rails 4 and have a `notifs` and a `users` model.

Each `notif` `has_many` `users` (aka which `user` have seen the `notif`). I'm trying to get all notifs that have not been seen by the `current_user`. In order to check if the `current_user` has seen a notif I'm using this model class:

```
def seen_by?(u)
  return self.users.include?(u)
end
```

How can I use a call to get all notifs where `seen_by(current_user)` is `true`?

Something like:

```
Notif.where(seen_by(current_user): true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need an anti-join pattern here, that can be performed with `left join`/`is null`, `not in/subquery` or `not exists/subquery` check, for example. The problem with the first is that you can't specify condition in the `on` clause without raw sql (or rewriting associations). So you can go here with `not in` and a separate query approach:

```
Notif.where.not(id: User.where(id: current_user_id).pluck[:notif_id])
```